# Angular interpolation expression not evaluated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am having an issue with Angular interpolation.

I have a directive template that looks like this:

```
<div class="autocomplete {{attrs.class}}" id="{{attrs.id}}">
     <input type="text" {{attrs.autofocus | toAutofocusText}} ng-model="searchParam" placeholder="{{attrs.placeholder}}"/>
     ...
</div>
```

The problem I have is that this expression is not evaluated:

```
{{attrs.autofocus | toAutofocusText}}
```

However, if I change this to something like this:

```
x="{{attrs.autofocus | toAutofocusText}}"
```

It does get evaluated.

Could someone explain me why this would be happening? I am guessing it is something fairly fundamental, but I can't find anything on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is that attributes don't get interpolated on that level. Or to be more specific, at the time when your HTML is compiled, angular processes DomElements. A Dom element with an attribute that starts with `{{` isn't a valid attribute, which is why the `$compile` don't know about it. However, it **does** now about such expressions within attribute values, or Dom element contents.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that angular is (they say) what html would be if written for applications. The data binding syntax is evaluated as html. Saying:

```
x="{{attrs.autofocus | toAutofocusText}}"
```

is different because now you are talking about an attribute's property being evaluated not some unknown characters inside an html element.

Another thing I would recommend is you look into using ng-class for manipulating the class stuff:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. In my case I wanted to apply an  angular directive to the input element. I just figured out that I can use a function to resolve a template and got it to work. Instead of trying to have an expression in template I now just concatenate strings in my template function.